# How to increase the No. of processors in JVM?

Tags: jvm, alfresco

HI,

I deployed Alfresco server in six core AMD opteron... but the jconsole is showing the Number of processors: 2

How can i increase the no.of processors...

Regards,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the machine have discovered the processors? How many do you see in top/htop on Linux or task manager on Windows?